# Should DBA.META.SE Have a Featured And/Or FAQ Tag

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Based on Max Vernon's recent Meta Post request for a MCVE Page in the Help Centre on DBA.SE I initially posted an answer with an alternative idea for making information visible. Because I changed my answer in response to Max' feedback, I still find the idea quite interesting and would like to bring it up again in a question.

### Introduction

Some questions and answers here on DBA.META.SE have some valuable information that I think should be rewarded with additional visibility.

Over on META.SE there are Q&A that receive a <kbd>featured</kbd> tag or a <kbd>faq</kbd> tag.

I propose that we introduce the same mechanism/feature for Q&As on META.DBA.SE

### Featured Tag

I think we should introduce a <kbd>featured</kbd> (or <kbd>dba-featured</kbd>) tag like on Meta which allows certain important posts to be tagged and locked in an orange box in the side bar.

**Example:**

[image: Meta Stackexchange with Sidebard]

### FAQ Tag

We could supplement the featured tag with an <kbd>faq</kbd> tag that would allow us to have a list of important Q&As in the side bar like in the above screenshot taken from META.SE.

### Moderation

Moderators will be allowed to set the tags on Q&As in DBA.META.SE that should be either <kbd>featured</kbd> and/or deemed relevant as <kbd>faq</kbd>.

What do you think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We already have both [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) and [faq](/questions/tagged/faq). Both are moderator only.

Featured meta posts appear on the main site sidebar for 30 days.

The "frequently asked" section is currently only populated for meta.SE and meta.SO. If you would to see this added to our local meta, please contibute to [Pinning/sticking good (canonical) questions/answers to top of board](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2995)