# Pinning/sticking good (canonical) questions/answers to top of board

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I was wondering whether it would be a good idea for moderators (based on popular demand) to be able to pin/stick posts at the top of the meta questions list (as is done [here](http://www.orafaq.com/forum/f/1/)).

Two posts that I would like to see pinned to the top of the meta board are [this one](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql) and [this one](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2990/minimal-complete-and-verifiable-example) as I find myself constantly referring to them in replies to new (and not so new :-( ) users.

Any thoughts?

Comment: there's a featured on meta side bar that effectively does this.  i believe there's also the ability to schedule events?